# For the sinusoidal graph below, write the equation in form $y = a\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{p}x\right)+b$

Tags: graphing-functions

For the sinusoidal graph below, write the equation

$$y = a\cos \left(\frac{2\pi}{p}x\right) + b.$$

The answer I solved it to be looking at the graph is

$$y = 25\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{12}x\right) + 30$$

Thanks any input or help would be appreciated :D

[image: the plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything to add; your answer is correct.

Comment: are you sure? or are you just sayign that.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Is there other input you are looking for besides confirmation that your answer is correct?